# TypeScript - How to infer a type from array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I am building a React form component with TypeScript and want to type the data returned by my form.

My component accepts a prop called "fields" with the following structure:

```
const fields = [
   {
      name: "title",
      default: "",
      data: undefined,
      size: 2
   },
   {
      name: "users",
      default: [],
      data: [{id: 1, ...}]
      size: 8
   },
]
```

I would like to find a way to retrieve the type of the data returned by component based on the "field" variable. So, basically, I want to get something like that:

```
type FormData = {
   title: string;
   users: Array<{id: number, ...}>
}
```

The best solution would be to infer a different type depending on the "data" key. If "data" exists, then the field will have the same type as data, otherwise it is the type of the "default" key. All other keys should be ignored.

I believe I should be using generics to achieve this but I am not even sure this is something possible with TS and I have to admit that I can't figure it out...

Has anyone already faced this situation and found a solution to a similar issue ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given array `fields`, we can create the type `FormData` with the following generic type as long as the `fields` variable was initialized with `as const` to stop TypeScript from widening the `string` literals.

```
const fields = [
  {
      name: "title",
      default: "",
      data: undefined,
      size: 2
  },
  {
      name: "users",
      default: [],
      data: [{id: 1}],
      size: 8
  },
] as const

type FormData<T extends readonly { name: st
  [E in T[number] as E["name"]]: E["data"] 
    ? E["default"]
    : E["data"]
}

type Result = FormData<typeof fields>
// type Result = {
//   title: "";
//   users: readonly [{
//       readonly id: 1;
//   }];
// }
```

This might or might not work in the context of your component. But you did not show us the component itself. This is a solution based on the information given in your question.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAMwCYoN7GClRAexBgBd0BLKAGwxhQF4UBtfAndjj8aALhQAiMpTI0oggDRduKDFDRgArjTIDBUmdwxgyYAUpDy0lEFAzTZHGJQBeUAQCYZAX0sdcVgrwdClMKAAnGE0vOQVlVQEWAF13Kx09aOxKDAEARhc4rWs7XwAOV3cYlDAGYlIyPAIyAE84VAAxIkCIABFdMAAeABUUKAAPMigjBkCoMAwSGlqcFB8BckDTAHNJcMUVNVKQWvXE-R3Zl1iAPiZObhYAURRTFB6WECUIACMgkrKUa5ZBH0EYjEBD9BAcAf0hiN6ChDMZTOYcgB%20b6-YyRMgAnLA1GdTEEFzVFB1BooABKsC2F2arQ6ei6xKgRDQVFo9FO7AA9ByifVUOSYJTmJ4UFyOCIxL4NABuTncgj%20IIwATjSbTWYsYWiqwqqYgGZ3NIodIyghalBZE0i7kEgl4PBAA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! This is close, but sadly I can't use "as const" as I would lose the type safety on the component props...

Comment: @AxelDS. - There probably is a solution for you. But you need to show the whole context of this problem. Otherwise this just becomes guess work.